# Is there a way to send a value with OAuth RequestToken request and get it back with the reply?

Tags: twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

In my application users send many requests to twitter api. I want to map the request with the response. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add query parameters to call back url when we made the oauth token request. Those will be returned back. That is the way. Refer https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/19419